# Complex roots in 2nd polynomial

Tags: r

I am dealing with the roots of a seconf order polynomial and I only wnat to store the complex roots ( the ones that only have imaginary part). When I do:

```
Im(roots)) 
[1] -1.009742e-28  1.009742e-28
```

So the program says that is not equal to 0. And so the condition

```
Im(roots) ==0
```

Is never true. And I am storing all the roots that are only real also.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a case of FAQ 7.31 (dealing with representation and comparison of floating point numbers). The `all.equal` function is available in such cases. Best use would be

```
> isTRUE(all.equal(roots[1], 0) )
[1] TRUE
> isTRUE(all.equal(roots[2], 0) )
[1] TRUE
```

Read `?all.equal` for all the gory details.

Answer (score 2):

DWin is almost certainly right that you're getting numbers with magnitudes that small due to the imprecision of floating point arithmetic.

To correct for it in your application, you might want to use `zapsmall(x, digits)`. `zapsmall()`  is nice utility function that will round to 0 numbers that are very close to (within `digits` decimal places of) it.

Here, riffing off an example from its help page:

```
thetas <- 0:4*pi/2
coords <- exp(1i*thetas)
coords
# [1]  1+0i  0+1i -1+0i  0-1i  1-0i

## Floating point errors obscure the big picture
Im(coords) == 0
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Re(coords) == 0
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

## zapsmall makes it all better
Im(zapsmall(coords)) == 0
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
Re(zapsmall(coords)) == 0
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```